# what's the difference between $('#') and document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

```
 var mysel = document.getElementById("mySelect")); 
 mysel.val("1")
```

and

```
 var myobj = $("#mySelect"); 
 mysel.val("1")
```

In my case, I am going to change the default select option. But I can't make it work with `getElementById`. By rewritting it with `$("#mySelect")`, it works.

So I am confused about the difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first one can be corrected with `mysel.value = "1";`. Also you have an extra trailing `)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a DOM element object.

`$` returns a jQuery object. Passing it a string containing an id selector causes it to populate the jQuery object with a DOM element object.

`val` is a jQuery method, not a DOM element method.